# ShieldUI Grid Export to PDF options

Tags: pdf, export-to-pdf, shieldui

I am working with the ShieldUI Grid control and have setup a pretty standard sample, similar to this [sample](https://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-general/export-to-pdf). 
As demonstrated in it, I have setup the datasource and standard options, however I would like to change the paper size and possibly orientation, since the layout is somewhat bulky. Any pointers in the right direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Paper size and orientation can be changed using the 
exportOptions.pdf.size and exportOptions.pdf.orientation properties. 
For example:

```
exportOptions: {
    pdf: {
        size: "a4",
        orientation: "portrait",
        ...
    }
}
```

More information can be found in [this documentation page](https://www.shieldui.com/documentation/grid/javascript/api/settings/exportOptions/pdf).